# RecyclerView adapter connection error: no adapter attached

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to use RecyclerView in a fragment but i cannot connect the adapter. when i run it, it fails and i get this error

**E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**

> Fragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private CardAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container,false);
        rv= (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>() ;
        words.add("x");
        words.add("x");
        words.add("x");
        adapter= new CardAdapter(getActivity(),words);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it now, you're re-inflating the layout, and returning one that hasn't set an adapter for the RecyclerView.  Just return the one you already inflated and used to set up the RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container,false);
    rv= (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>() ;
    words.add("x");
    words.add("x");
    words.add("x");
    adapter= new CardAdapter(getActivity(),words);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Return the view that you already inflated:
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return view , you inflate the layout and get recyclerview,you shouldn't inflate twice. just return the first inflate view